# Shape of the graph spectrum

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Given a simple, undirected graph with maximum degree $d$. Let its spectrum be the eigenvalues of the associated adjacency matrix. It is known that this spectrum lies between $-d$ and $d$.

Is it possible to say anything stronger about the shape of the spectrum?

As two extreme cases I would like to distinguish, consider the spectrum of the complete graph versus the spectrum of the cycle:

- complete graph over $N$ nodes: spectrum $\{N,0\}$, where $0$ is $(N-1)$-fold degenerate. I.e., the spectrum is very peaked.
- cycle over $N$ nodes: spectrum $\{\cos(2\pi k/N)|k\in[0,N)\}$. I.e., the spectrum is almost evenly distributed.

Comment: People usually think about this the other way around: if I knew the spectrum then what can I infer about the graph? For instance for the related problem with the graph Laplacian of a connected graph, the smallest nonzero eigenvalues is a measure of the connectivity of the graph.

Comment: Sure, and I am aware of the graph properties that are closely tied to the spectral gap.The spectral gap on itself however does not tell you anything about the shape of the spectrum. An interesting counterexample would be the dumbbell graph, i.e., two complete graphs connected by a single edge. Its spectral gap would be similar to the one of the cycle, its shape however will be very close to the spectrum of the complete graph.